# StoredProcedure invocation using Spring JPA results in error

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using hibernate JPA to execute an stored procedure in spring application but it is resulting in below error. StoredPrcoedure does not have any parameters so below error is not intuitive. Any google search around this resulted in no results and references to spring/hibernate documentation also did not help. Any help around this would be greatly appreciated. I cannot seem to understand what I am doing wrong and totally stuck at this point..

> Error:
>
> org.hibernate.procedure.NoSuchParameterException: Could not locate
>   parameter registered using that position [1]  at
>   org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getParameterRegistration(ProcedureCallImpl.java:338)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.getOutputParameterValue(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:68)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.getOutputParameterValue(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:276)

Entity class as below:

```
    @Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getCountries", procedureName = "spLT_Countries", resultClasses = Country.class)
public class Country implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "countryid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ISOCountrycode")
    private String iso2;

    @Column(name="Country")
    private String name;
        :
        :
}
```

Stored procedure in MS SQL Server, existing one which I cannot modify.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spLT_Countries]
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    Set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
    Select countryid, ISOCountrycode, Country from RN_Country order by Country

end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have no way to make further progress.

Comment: How do you call the stored procedure?

Comment: I am using JPA annotation - @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getCountries", procedureName = "spLT_Countries", resultClasses = Country.class) which invokes the procedure but it fails on mapping the parameters

Comment: `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` just declares the query. It doesn't invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EntityManager` of `JPA` to return the result of the stored procedure like this:

```
  javax.persistence.Query query=em.createNativeQuery("exec getCountries");  
  List<country> results = query.getResultList();
```

You may need to remove unnecessary annotations from `country` class.

Comment: Thanks Farhang, that works but I wanted to just use JPA annotation rather than using EntityManager directly.